# A multiple of 10 and 100

Tags: number-theory

- $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ and $x,y$ are integers such that $x^{2} + xy + y^{2}$ is a multiple of $10$.
- Show that it must be a multiple of $100$ as well.

Comment: I multiplied $(x-y) $ to both sides, which gave me $x^3-y^3$ is a multiple of 10 as well. I didn't know how to proceed after that. @NoahSchweber

Comment: Is that useful in the proof?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are integers?

Comment: Yes they are. I'll add that in the question. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: Have you made tables of options $\pmod{2}$ and $\pmod{5}$?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^2 + xy + y^2$ is a multiple of $10$, $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy + y^2)$ is too.

Consider the squares and cubes of integers $\bmod 10$,

$$\begin{align*}
n &\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9&&\pmod {10}\\
n^2 &\equiv 0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1 &&\pmod{10}\\
n^3 &\equiv 0, 1, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 9 &&\pmod{10}
\end{align*}$$

Note that the cubes have different remainders modulo $10$, so in order to have $x^3-y^3\equiv 0\pmod{10}$, $x\equiv y\pmod {10}$.

Consider $x^2 + xy + y^2 \pmod{10}$,

$$\begin{align*}
x^2 + xy + y^2 &\equiv 0 &&\pmod{10}\\
3x^2 &\equiv 0\\
x^2 &\equiv 0\\
x &\equiv 0\\
y &\equiv 0
\end{align*}$$

Let $x = 10m$, $y = 10n$. Consider $x^2 + xy + y^2 \pmod {100}$,

$$\begin{align*}
x^2 + xy + y^2 &\equiv 100m^2 + 100 mn + 100n^2 &&\pmod{100}\\
&\equiv 0
\end{align*}$$

Comment: After finding that $x-y$ is a multiple of $10$, isn't it much faster to conclude that $x \equiv y \pmod{10}$, so $x^2+xy+y^2 \equiv 3x^2 \pmod{10}$, implying that $x \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$?

Comment: @Théophile Good point, let me rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2=xy+y^2$ is odd if $x,y$ are odd or if $x,y$ have opposite parity.

So, $x,y$ must be even

So, it is sufficient to show $x^2+xy+y^2\equiv0\pmod{25}$

Now  $x^2+xy+y^2\equiv0\pmod5\iff(2x+y)^2\equiv-3y^2$

If $5\nmid y,$ this implies $$\left(\dfrac{2x+y}y\right)^2\equiv-3\equiv2\pmod5$$

But for any integer $a, a^2\equiv0,\pm1\pmod5$

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't follow the solution. Could you please briefly explain why you followed these steps?

Comment: The goal is to show that $x$ and $y$ are both even, and then that they are both multiplies of 5, so that they must both be multiples of 10. But the logic is indeed very terse above

Comment: More logic should def be added. It took me a while to figure it out.Line 4 is basically rewriting the equation. It is saying the same thing on both sides, except the right side is multiplied by 4, which is valid because it lab is basically rewriting x as (2x) and y as (2y), and he has proved that each variable is even. Then line 5 is taking that equation and dividing y^2 on both sides. I'm not sure how this logic works out because it seems like  he's taking the modulus of a fraction. Anyways, he shows that it always would have remainder 2 and that it is impossible for a square to have R=2mod5.